# How can I have multiples database in symfony for multiples clients?

Tags: php, database, symfony, multi-tenant

I got a legacy code in symphony, but the systems works like this for each client has a system and one database, but the both are same for all of them, so i have "twenty" same systems "folders" for each client and each client has a database.

So, I'm trying to change this to one folder for all clients, but I've been having a problem with the databases, because the file .env we can set only one database for .env file, so, in this case i think to create a folder inside the system "envs" and i created for each client one .env with their names
Example: .envtest, .envgoogle, .envfacebook and etc...
And i use this function on public/index.php to set the corret .env

(new Dotenv())->load(**DIR**.'/../envs/.env'.explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])[0]);

and when client trying to access the system i get from the $_SERVER the URL how i can concat and get the corret .env

but i think that i'm doing too wrong, there is other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your problem. You can ask the creaters of symfony and they can help you. Just write your question in thier website here (choose any course and then put your question):
https://symfonycasts.com/

In my case, I have so many databases for my clients but in diffrent servers (LDAP and Soap) so it was easy for me. but in your case it is better to ask Symfony creater themselves.